# Evernote.SDK is not compatible with UWP apps

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, sdk, uwp, evernote

I just signed up for an Evernote API key and downloaded the Evernote SDK for Windows in Visual Studio 2015 (suing NuGet) only to be told "Evernote.SDK 1.25.0 is not compatible with uap10.0".... so it seems it only supports .Net v4.0 which is very disappointing.  I had a great idea for a UWP app that I wanted to synch to Evernote but I guess now I can't do it.

In case you're not aware UWP (Universal Windows Platform) is now the standard for developing current and future Windows 10 apps that run across all W10 devices.  Can anyone at Evernote tell me if the SDK will support this and if so when?  More people already use Windows 10 than use iOS (on PC's and tablets at least) so I really hope this platform will be supported in the very near future.

Answer (score 1):

From the 1.25 version number you mention, it sounds like you're trying to grab the older C# SDK.  You can try the [newer SDK for Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/) and see if that works.

If that NuGet package also doesn't work in your UWP environment, you should be able to grab [the source from Github](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows) and put that in your VS solution.

Comment: Thanks Phil - it appears the CloudSDK also targets v4.0.  However, I'll get the source and see if that work in an UWP app.